# Convert mysql subquery to join because phalcon php framework query builder does not support subquery

Tags: join, subquery, phalcon

I am stacking to write a query for couple of days, appreciate if someone can advice me. I have written query using SUB QUERY but limitation is that I am using PHALCON PHP FRAMEWORK which query builder does not support sub query yet. So need some advice to get it convert with JOINS.

MORE DETAILS:

I need to fetch posts in order to latest entry in post_notification table. Well, I am building an application where I have to rearrange the posts list based on latest notification user received.

QUERY I WRITTEN:

```
SELECT p.* , ( SELECT creation_date  FROM uo_notifications AS n
                            WHERE n.post_id = p.id
                            AND n.user_id = ".$user_id ."
                            ORDER BY n.id DESC
                            LIMIT 1
                          ) AS cdate
            FROM uo_posts AS p
            WHERE p.user_id = ".$user_id."
                AND p.group_id = ".$group_id."
            ORDER BY cdate DESC
```

Posts table:

1. id PK
2. message
3. group_id
4. creation_date

post_notifications

1. id PK
2. user_id
3. notify_msg
4. post_id
5. creation_date

Thank you in advance for everyone who try to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting in join I have executed this query and get resultset with simple resultset type that work very well with Paginator class of Phalcon.

```
              // Base model
              $bm = new BaseModel();

              // Execute the query
             $rs = new Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple(null, $bm, $bm->getReadConnection()->query($sql));
```

Answer (score 0):

Now. Phalcon 2.x have support subquery, you can take look here http://phalcontip.com/discussion/44/subqueries-subquerieswow

Comment: Phalcon 2.x allow to have subquery in Where clause but subquery in column selection could not be parsed. It gives error: PhalconException: Syntax error, unexpected token SELECT. - https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/10453